# Looking for a standard way to manage documents in a WPF application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm writing a WPF application that uses one document at a time. Is there any standard way to implement the management of the current document? What I mean are the following functions:

1. New document: if there are not saved changes in the current document, a dialog box opens ('Do you want to save changes to {0}?') with Yes/No/Cancel buttons. If Cancel is hit, the operation stops.
2. Open document: same dialog box as at new document, and an Open dialog opens after
3. Save document: if the current document hasn't been saved, a Save dialog opens
4. Save as: you can imagine...

So, is there anything standard in the .NET framework like this or do I have to manually implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check out Acropolis, I've never used it myself but I think it would help you http://windowsclient.net/Acropolis/Default.aspx

Comment: It looks too heavy-weight to me to use a full application framework just to achieve this functionality. Besides, I already did implement most part of it in about 100 lines. And the fact that the project Acropolis is a dead project makes it something that I wouldn't like to integrate into my application.

So, I would like something else.

Comment: Hmmm didn't know it was dead, don't know of any other way to do what you want, sorry